# Was there a change in NumPy's asserts dealing with NaN

Tags: python, numpy

I am having troubles with running a code I wrote a year ago on an older system (Python 2.7 and I belive it was NumPy 1.6.1).
I built in a lot of "assert_array_almost_equal" to check the running of my program. As far as I checked my code I am comparing something like

```
>>> np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal([1.0,1.0,np.nan],
                                     np.ones(3))
```

which I wasn't aware of. This clealy raises an assertion error. However, since the code worked fine on the previous system, I wondered whether something changed in "assert_array_almost_equal" and it simply ignored NaNs before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there have been any changes that would lead to the behavior you are describing. The documentation from Numpy 1.6.0 and 1.7.0 show the same behavior:

```
>>> np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal([1.0,2.33333,np.nan],
...                                      [1.0,2.33333, 5], decimal=5)
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>:
ValueError:
Arrays are not almost equal
 x: array([ 1.     ,  2.33333,      NaN])
 y: array([ 1.     ,  2.33333,  5.     ])
```

[Numpy 1.7.0 assert_array_almost_equal documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.7.0/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal.html#numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal)
[Numpy 1.6.0 assert_array_almost_equal documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal.html#numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal)